# IOS: Subclassing objects with replacing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, class, inheritance

I have class Project. I need to create class CheckboxProject that will be used with checkbox list, it will have property 'checked' and I will check/uncheck items.

So, I use inheritance and did it. But dataSource array is contains Project classes. How can I convert this array to CheckboxProject classes?

```
@interface Project : NSObject 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@end

@interface CheckboxProject : Project 
@property (nonatomic) BOOL checked;
@end
```

I have dataSourse array of Project. I need to convert it to array of CheckboxProject and then I need be able to change checked to YES/NO.

I need to get array of CheckboxProject from array of Project

Comment: Can you include some code examples? Are you talking about just casting? `(CheckboxProject *)item`

Comment: How are you filling the array? And where do you create the Project objects? You will need to create CheckboxProject objects and put those in the array because casting won't do any good if they are Project objects

Comment: Alex Reynolds, I create it after parsing, so it is not good idea, also I need this class and property 'checked' only once, so I need array of CheckboxProject

Comment: Please show code for where you populate the datasource array. If you populate it with Project objects you cannot just convert them later to CheckboxProject classes. Easiest solution is to just add the checked BOOL to the Project class

Comment: Alex Reynolds, can I copy it with <NSCopying, NSCoding>?

Comment: I don't think you can copy one object into another. You will need to post a lot more of your code in order to help you with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array in obj-c isnt type safe so you can put what ever you want inside.

You can check at runtime the class type

```
id obj = [array objectAtIndex:index];
if([obj isKindOfClass:[CheckmarkProject class]]) {
// do something with the checkmark
} else if ... // the other type of class {
}
```

but in any case it is *bad* practice to do such a thing. (I would prefer accessing the base class vars in the mix case)

Comment: oh, I am asking about other thing